# Python UTF-8 conversion problem

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding, utf-8

In my database, I have stored some UTF-8 characters. E.g. 'α' in the "name" field

Via Django ORM, when I read this out, I get something like

```
>>> p.name
u'\xce\xb1'
>>> print p.name
Î±
```

I was hoping for 'α'.

After some digging, I think if I did

```
>>> a = 'α'
>>> a
'\xce\xb1'
```

So when Python is trying to display '\xce\xb1' I get alpha, but when it's trying to display u'\xce\xb1', it's double encoding?

Why did I get u'\xce\xb1' in the first place? Is there a way I can just get back '\xce\xb1'?

Thanks. My UTF-8 and unicode handling knowledge really need some help...

Comment: Did you really store UTF-8 to the database? That's not so good...

Comment: You're getting a unicode literal containing a bytestring. Something somewhere is wrong - are you encoding it and then storing it in a unicode field? If you need to get the values back, `p.name..encode("iso-8859-1").decode("utf-8")` should do it, but it's not really solving the problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Hi , if you have the time to answer ,  what other options do you have when you need to store utf - 8 encoded unicode symbols to a database?

Comment: @KonstantinosChertouras: Don't. Use the database's native international character support properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the unicode signature `u` before your string, e.g. `u'YOUR_ALFA_CHAR'` and revise your database encoding, because Django always supports UTF-8 .

Comment: Sounds great if it's a string literal the OP is talking about, but I think it's coming from the database that way.

Comment: It's coming from the DB, I am not putting my own string literal. When I look at the DB using mysql command line tool, I see the alpha. The encoding is utf8, but when I load in Python, I get u'\xce\xb1', and not '\xce\xb1'.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to have is the individual bytes of a UTF-8 encoded string interpreted as unicode codepoints. You can "decode" your string out of this strange form with:

```
p.name = ''.join(chr(ord(x)) for x in p.name)
```

or perhaps

```
p.name = ''.join(chr(ord(x)) for x in p.name).decode('utf8')
```

One way to get your strings "encoded" into this form is

```
''.join(unichr(ord(x)) for x in '\xce\xb1')
```

although I have a feeling your strings actually got in this state by different components of your system disagreeing on the encoding in use.

You will probably have to fix the source of your bad "encoding" rather than just fixing the data currently in your database. And the code above might be okay to convert your bad data once, but I would advise you don't insert this code into your Django app.

Comment: A very nice and detailed explanation .

Comment: Can you please explain why chr(ord(x) will work if x > 255  since "chr (x) : Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i. ..The argument must be in the range [0..255], inclusive; ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range. "

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that p.name was not correctly stored and/or read in from the database.

Unicode small alpha is U+03B1 and p.name should have printed as u'\x03b1' or if you were using a Unicode capable terminal the actual alpha symbol itself may have been printed in quotes. Note the difference between u'\xce\xb1' and u'\xceb1'. The former is a two character string and the latter in a single character string. I have no idea how the '03' byte of the UTF-8 got translated into 'CE'.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the encoding with `p.name.encode('latin-1')`. Here's a demonstration:

```
>>> print u'\xce\xb1'
Î±
>>> print u'\xce\xb1'.encode('latin-1')
α
>>> print '\xce\xb1'
α
>>> '\xce\xb1' == u'\xce\xb1'.encode('latin1')
True
```

For more information, see [str.encode](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [Standard Encodings](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: I get '\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb1', from u'\xce\xb1'

Comment: Hmmm-- try encoding in `latin-1`. I hope that works! The `p.encode('utf-8')` may print "Î±"; it shouldn't print the string you had. String encoding is a very fickle beast! :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn any byte sequence into internal unicode representation through the decode function:

```
print '\xce\xb1'.decode('utf-8')
```

This allows you to import a byte sequence from any source and then turn it into a Python unicode string.

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: Problem is print u'\xce\xb1'.decode('utf-8'), not print '\xce\xb1'.decode('utf-8')