# Python deleting file with Unicode characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I am writing a cleanup method in Python 2 that should erase any files including the ones with unicode name. `shutil.rmtree` is not an option since it lacks the control I need.

At the moment what I tried was declaring `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and then use combinations of `.encode('utf-8')` and `.decode('utf-8')` but with no success. This is how my method looks without any encoding or decoding

```
def _remove_files(path):
    files = []

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in [f for f in filenames]:
            files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

    for _file in files:
        print _file
        os.chmod(_file, stat.S_IRWXU | stat.S_IRWXG | stat.S_IRWXO)
        os.remove(_file)
```

This is the error I get:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: u'C:\Users\xxxxx\yyyyy\\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\u306e\u656c\u8a9e.txt'

Comment: Is this for python2? What exactly isn't working? Are unicode files skipped?

Comment: I had the same problem. I found  useful guidelines here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050719/python-utf-8-conversion-problem for anyone interested.